# "What is it?" or "What is that?" (What's that?)

Tags: word-usage

When you refer to something the listener has, which question is appropriate?

1. What is it?
2. What is that? (What's that?)

[image: two people facing each other, one with a "?" speech balloon and the other holding a book]

In my mother tongue, Japanese, we use *sore* (literally meaning "it") when referring to something the listener has, and we use *are* (literally meaning "that") only when referring to something far from both of the speaker and the listener. I wonder whether this is the same in English or not.

Comment: これ = this, それ or あれ = that. ここ = here, そこ or あそこ = there.
Japanese distinguishes things related to the speaker, the listener, and other. English only distinguishes between things related to the speaker and other.

Comment: Do you mean that "What's that?" is the appropriate question to use in the situation?

Comment: The speaker *isn't* holding the thing being asked about, so by default that thing is ***somewhere else*** (not *"**here**, in my hands"*) - in which case the speaker would say *What's **that**?* or *What have you got **there**?* As opposed to the speaker having something in his hands, and asking *What is **this** thing I have **here**?*

Answer (score 1):

Japanese has a three way system of demonstratives. It distinguishes between things at a distance (in conversation close to the listener), things more immediate to the speaker, and things far away.

English has a two way system of demonstratives. It only distinguishes between things close to the speaker and everything else. Demonstratives come in pairs.

This - That

These - Those

This pattern also occurs with the location words "Here" and "There".

"It" as a pronoun contains no information that points to any specific object. Asking "What is it?" without a clear context is very ambiguous, so you would not normally ask the question that way.

The appropriate question to ask in this situation is "What is that?"

Comment: Is it fairly easy to come up with contexts in Japanese where the relevant "category" isn't completely clear-cut, so different speakers might use different demonstratives without this being particularly noticeable? There are certainly lots of contexts in English where *"What's this?"* and *"What's that?"* are completely interchangeable.

Comment: Aha! So perhaps if you're in a friend's house you might be more likely to use the equivalent ***that*** rather than ***this*** to ask about something on the bookshelf simply because it's ***his*** bookshelf, even though *at time of asking*, you might be physically closer to it than him. That happens in English, but people don't spend a lot of time thinking about which to use, and if you *do* make a different choice to what others would say, it wouldn't normally be noticed anyway. Just "nearer = this", "further = that" as an *approximate* rule of thumb is usually all it takes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am not actually a native speaker, and would have to ask one about that specific situation, but that's the general idea, yes. I do know that if you picked up the book you would absolutely use "this" in a way that overrides other considerations.

Comment: Yeah - if the speaker has something *in his hand*, it's difficult to imagine a context where he'd refer to it as ***that***. Maybe if Mom goes into teenager's bedroom, pulls out a hastily-hidden ashtray from under the bed, and stretches her arm out holding the still-smoking butt in son's face while saying *"What's **that**?"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I actually believe that I have made incorrect interpretations about psychological distance here, and what I said about ownership by the listener is incorrect. Please disregard it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150761/discussion-between-yonkuma-and-fumblefingers).

Comment: "this/that" are deictic pronouns, "it" is not.

Comment: No! The demonstratives "this/that/these/those" are not pronouns but determinatives.

Comment: @BillJ Wouldn't they be pronouns in this context? "What is this? This is a book" vs "This book is red".

Comment: @YonKuma No: in the independent use ("This is mine") they function as fused determiner-head in NP structure. And in the dependent use ("This milk is sour") they function as pre-head determiner.

Answer (score 0):

"It" and "that" can both be used to refer to things far or near. I would say, loosely and I may be wrong, that "it" would be used only when you've already referred to the thing previously, whereas "that" would be used when it's the first time referring to the thing.

An example of "it" when the thing has already been referred to:

> That's a neat box you're holding. What is it?

And example of "that" when it hasn't already been referred to yet:

> *pointing at the thing in your friend's hand* What is that?

Answer (score -1):

*What is this*.

The picture suggests the item held literally at hand's reach, which grants "this". Something farther from the speaker would be "What is that".

"What is it" has an entirely different meaning - it's a mildly impatient informal phrase meaning "State your problem", "What is the issue?". If the girl in the photo was pouting showing the item broken, "What is it" would be a reasonable thing to say, with expected reply "Can you fix it please?". It's equivalent to "How can I help you?" but devoid of politeness, not outright rude but not polite either.

Comment: You might also ask "What is it?" if the other person had already referred to the object,. saying "Look at this" or similar.